# Default values to Application settings vs 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, application-settings

Within my vb.net project I have a form that acts as a settings page. This page contains some open dialogue functionality that allows the user to define the specified file paths.

I have this to set to save once the application is closed and I seem to have it working well.

When the program is then distributed the settings page is cleared however the program fails to load as its looking paths in certain parts of the code which would yet to be defined.

My question is do I

a) set default values into the application settings which point generally to the right file path (ideal scenario as the paths are only distinguishable by user name although I'm not sure how to accomplish this)

or

b) apply some code that ignores the file locations if they are not there and open the program anyway

A bit of advice would be great and i can post any code that may be helpful

Thanks

Comment: That is way too broad, friend. There's no way you can get the exact right answer. There are tons of different ways of having default settings and no one could possibly tell how not knowing the file paths will affect your running application. Be more specific.

Comment: Very broad, but even if/when you have user defined paths, those might have changed or no longer exist the next time you run, so the app should test them anyway.